# How to read this.$$('#startdate').value on WCT using polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0, web-component-tester, wct

I'm unable to read the value from this.$$('#startdate').value to WebComponentTest(WCT)

```
startDate = this.$$('#startdate').value
```

Comment: please postethe code of your test aswell as your components code

Comment: Could you please show a working example of the code? i.e. what do your objects look like?

Comment: when i read this.$$('#startdate').value im getting ERROR: this.$$ is not a function in WCT

Comment: Please check the code in this link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCBJ1.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not referenced to the polymer and webcomponent.min.js file under your scripts section.